# Rebuild a FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, future, rebuild

I am trying to rebuild a FutureBuilder, in my case it is for the purpose of changing the camera that is shown to the user. For that I have to run the Future, the FutureBuilder uses again.
The Future currently looks like this:

```
body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeCameraControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return CameraPreview(_cameraController);
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
```

The Future it is running is this one:

```
Future<void> _initializeCameraControllerFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (camerafrontback != true) {
      _cameraController =
          CameraController(widget.camera[0], ResolutionPreset.veryHigh);
    }else{
      _cameraController =
          CameraController(widget.camera[1], ResolutionPreset.veryHigh);
    }
    _initializeCameraControllerFuture = _cameraController.initialize();
  }
```

I have a button that should trigger this rebuild of the FutureBuilder, it is also changing the 'camerafrontback' Boolean, so that a different camera is used. It is shown below:

```
IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              if (camerafrontback == true){
                setState(() {
                  camerafrontback = false;
                });
              }else{
                setState(() {
                  camerafrontback = true;
                });
              };

            },
```

At the end, before the last bracket, there must be a statement added that triggers the rebuilds of  whole FutureBuilder, but I couldn't find one that suits to my code.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: It doesn't seem like just triggering a rebuild of the `FutureBuilder` will solve your problem. Just changing the value of `camerafrontback` doesn't seem to do anything where we would expect the camera to change as far as I can tell with this code.

Comment: What chaining `camerafrontback` does is that it changes in Future the camera from `camera[0]` to camera `camera[1]` or the other way around with that `if` statement

Comment: In your original code, the only place that variable is checked is in `initState`, so even if the variable is changed, there is nothing to check that and change the camera controller unless you dispose and reinitialize the whole widget.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Yes then that is what I have to do, so what would be the workaround for it?

Comment: @AjayKumar's answer does this already. He calls the `_init` method that he created in the `onPressed` of the button in addition to during `initState`.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I have used it but had to put the `_init` into brackets like this: `setState(() {_init() });` in order to get it to work. It works fine in the simulator, but on my outdate android phone it shows a black screen, when I try to flip the camera, just as a side note.

Comment: Yes the answer wasn't quite correct there. I believe you could also just do `setState(_init);` as well. Have you ever gotten the camera to work correctly? Or is it just with this edited code?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Yes, it worked alright this morning, but I have just found out that there is a camera error. So nothing is wrong with the code. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinitialize`_initializeCameraControllerFuture`.

You can do it something like this

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _init();
  }

  ...


  _init() {
    if (camerafrontback) {
        _cameraController =
          CameraController(widget.camera[1], ResolutionPreset.veryHigh);

    } else {
         _cameraController =
          CameraController(widget.camera[0], ResolutionPreset.veryHigh);
    }
    _initializeCameraControllerFuture = _cameraController.initialize();
  }


  ...


  IconButton(
  onPressed: () async {
           if (camerafrontback) {
              camerafrontback = false;
              setState(_init());
      } else {
            camerafrontback = true;
             setState(_init);
             }
           },
         ),
```

Comment: Is there anything that I have to do with the `FutureBuilder`? Because the camera gets activated but the preview is not shown on the screen.

Comment: having similar problem how do i get the future builder to reload after state has changed

Answer (score -1):

to full rebuild your screen you can just replace the screen with the same screen

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
       *SamePage*()
  )
);
```